# How to create hyperlink text for app deeplinking

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, deep-linking, android-sharing

Actual Requirement

- click on share button
- generate a text/url/link
- share this with other users via whatsapp/fb/twitter/email etc.
- onclick of this link, my app opens with data passed in the link.
- similar to youtube link like: https://youtu.be/g5MIJ3Us10k

What Is done till now...
I have a deeplink URL in String form.
It works perfectly when I access it as the hyperlink on a browser and my app opens correctly.
I need to create this URL string as hyperlink that can be shared among other apps from the app itself.

Using following code to generate share link

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "MyAPPLink");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url); //String deeplink url
        return shareIntent;
```

I able to share text to other apps, but it's not a link rather plain text.
How can I make it a hyperlink, so that when user share it to the other app, other users can click on the link and open the app and pass the data in the link?

**UPDATE**
Following is the deeplink url format
url = intent://#Intent;scheme=;package=;S.browser_fallback_url=;end;

**UPDATE 2**
I have created a link to my website and appended my deeplink data
like http://example.com/deeplink?id=1234567

I have uploaded a HTML file without UI and using JS I am able fetch my ID in the script.
Now when script runs, my app is not launching but divert to fallback url.

If I put a button in HTML and onclick of that button I run the script, my application launches.

How can I launch my app from generated shared text???

Comment: a url is just text. It is up to the app that receives it to work out what to do with it.

Comment: Could we see the contents of your HTML/JS redirect file? You could also check out [Branch.io](https://branch.io), since then you won't need to worry about all of these technical things.

Comment: I skimmed through Branch.io not sure if its free or paid!!
I am trying to learn new skill so I would prefer my own logic :)

HTML script is what I made for the client, need to remove a lot of unwanted code.
I will put snippets from JS soon.

Please see how youtube shares its links. Need similar approach.

Comment: Branch is completely free :). Learning a new skill is an awesome idea, though to be honest handling all the deep linking edge cases is one of the most complex things out there right now. Even big guys like Pinterest and HotelTonight use Branch for it.

Comment: I can open my app if I click a link inside a browser.. But not from other app :(

Answer (score 0):

I think I have resolved it. It is now working on my device with the chrome browser as default. Need to test with other combinations.

The issue was with JS. I put my redirect call inside setTimeout() and it worked.

Here is the logical flow

- Create an intent filter with scheme, view action and browsable+default category in manifest
- Create a share intent and setExtra text as http://example.com/deeplink?id=12345
- Create an empty HTML file and using JS, fetch the query and extract "id"
- Now using setTimeout(), call redirect deep link URL --> intent://#Intent;scheme=;package=;S.browser_fallback_url=;end;
- In the Activity exposed to deeplink, get dataString from intent and extract ID passed by deeplink

I hope this helps others :)